# How to reference another Model inside a given Model (Java Web)?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a `Movie.java` model with the following section:

```
@Column(name = "genre")
private Integer genre;
```

In my DB, the table `Movie` has a column named `genre` which is a FK from my `Genre` table.

`Genre.java` is yet another model with only two atributes: `id` which is auto-generated by the MySQL DB and `name`. How can I reference `Genre` so that when I'm using an instance of `Movie` I can call `.getGenre()` and receive a `Genre` object and not the `id`.

I'm using Java EE 7, Hibernate 4.3.11 and GlassFish 4.1.1

Comment: Suppose you add `private Genre genere` in your `Movie.java`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that Movie and Genre is `OneToMany` mapping, this is a example code:

```
public class Movie {
        // ...

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="movie")
        private Set<Genre> genres;
        // getter and setter
    }
```

Genre.java

```
public class Genre {
    // ...
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="genre")
    private Movie movie;
}
```

You can refer to [this link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-many-to-many-annotation-mapping-tutorial/) to implement a `ManyToMany` annotation mapping.

Comment: A more realistic real-world mapping would be a `@ManyToOne` or even perhaps `@ManyToMany` should movies actually fall within multiple genres.

Comment: Yes, ManyToOne or ManyToMany would be more suitable for this scenario.